# Use jQuery to move WordPress post attachments to per-post dynamically-created lists?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html-lists, posts

My goal is to strip the images and iframes out of WordPress posts (they are in .para divs) and move them to a `<ul>` above the post, just inside the local wrapper (.wrapper940).

The jQuery below works, but moves ALL image and iframes from all posts to a single new `<ul>` above the first post. Instead of this, I am trying to move the images and iframes PER POST to a new `<ul>` just inside the wrapper of each post.

Here's the jQuery:

```
jQuery("document").ready (function($){
    var matchesEl = $(".para img, .para iframe");
    if ( matchesEl.length > 0) {

    var newUl = $("<ul></ul>");
    newUl.prependTo(matchesEl.parents(".wrapper940"));

    matchesEl.each(function() {

        var newLi = $("<li></li>").append($(this)).appendTo(newUl);

        });

    }   
});
```

The html is:

```
<div class="news-item-wrap">
<div class="date">the date</div>
<div class="wrapper940">
    <div class="title">the title</div>
    <div class="para">
        <p>The main content of the post.</p>
        <p>Which could be several paragraphs</p>
        <p>And include iframes...</p>
        <p><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/uGMbZNTym-g" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">...</iframe>
        </p>
        <p>Followed by more text... and maybe some images....</p>
        <p><a href="http://www.joujouka.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/festival-interculture.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-404" alt="festival intercultural" src="http://www.joujouka.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/festival-interculture-213x300.jpg" width="213" height="300"/></a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="news-item-wrap">
<div class="date">the date</div>
<div class="wrapper940">
    <div class="title">the title</div>
    <div class="para">
        <p>A second post would follow like this.</p>
        <p>Which could also be several paragraphs</p>
        <p>And include iframes...</p>
        <p><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/uGMbZNTym-g" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">...</iframe>
        </p>
        <p>Followed by more text... and maybe some images....</p>
        <p><a href="http://www.joujouka.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/festival-interculture.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-404" alt="festival intercultural" src="http://www.joujouka.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/festival-interculture-213x300.jpg" width="213" height="300"/></a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This would continue for as many posts as there were. So I need to be able to move the images and iframes FOR EACH POST to appear just inside the .wrapper940 that wraps EACH POST. (i.e. above the title of each post.)

I think that using `.parents()` is sending all images and iframes from all posts to the first `.wrapper940`; `.closest()` seems like it should work, but doesn't, maybe because it breaks the loop?

Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
jQuery("document").ready (function($){
  var matchesEl = ".para a:has(img), .para iframe"
  $('.wrapper940').each(function(index){

    if ($(this).find(matchesEl).length > 0) {

      $('<ul>').insertBefore($(this).children('.title'));

      $(this).find(matchesEl).each(function() {
        //The line code under will only works if all your .wrappers940 always have at least one matched element.
        //$("<li>").append($(this)).appendTo($('.wrapper940 ul').eq(index));
        //So the right code is:
        $("<li>").append($(this)).appendTo($('.wrapper940').eq(index).children('ul'));
      });

    }
    $('p').filter(function () { return $.trim(this.innerHTML) == "" }).remove();
  });
});
```

Commenting code:

1) If you want only to move the image, you use `.para img`, but I think you want to move the element `<a>` with the `<img>`, so you can use: `.para a:has(img)`.

2) The `index` var here `$('.wrapper940').each(function(index){` is important to match the right ul in this line: `$("<li>").append($(this)).appendTo($('.wrapper940 ul').eq(index));`

3) This line will remove blank `<p>` tags: `$('p').filter(function () { return $.trim(this.innerHTML) == "" }).remove();` after you move their content into `<li>`s

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wDmsi

Answering your questions in comments:

1) The `index` is the index number of your element matched in `each()`. The base number is 0. So if you have 10 .wrapper940 in your page, the first one will have index = 0, the second will have index = 1, til the last and 10th will have index = 9. We use it here to force code not send the img and iframes to the wrong .wrapper940. It says img and iframes from .wrapper940 index 6 belongs to .wrapper940 index 6. Writing this I just discovered a fail in my code. Check the code above to see the changes.

2) I always used `this` for pure javascript and `$(this)` for jquery. It seems like `$(this)` have more properties, like we see here: [Difference between $(this) and this in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633270/difference-between-this-and-this-in-jquery) but using the `$(...)` consume more processing. So you can always test if both works on each case and use just `this`.

3) You can simplify:

```
var newUl = $("<ul></ul>");
newUl.insertBefore($(this).children('.title'));
```

To

```
$('<ul></ul>').insertBefore($(this).children('.title'));
```

And from this to

```
$('<ul>').insertBefore($(this).children('.title'));
```

4) The funcion `appendTo()`, `insertBefore()` and similars are already a kind of echo. I believe that if the element exist, the jQuery will move it. If it won't exist, jQuery will create it, but I can't confirm conclusively.

5) This trick of clear `<p>` tags is kind magic to me too. I don't know exactly how it works. I got the code from here: [Remove "empty" paragraphs with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823914/remove-empty-paragraphs-with-jquery)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be catching the iframes? Or is that a quirk of Codepen?

Comment: Oh, It is working! I removed unintentionally from html. Corrected on Codepen!

Comment: Fantastic - thankyou! Yes, I noticed that also and was simultaneously correcting!

Comment: Can I fling one more question at you - a variant on this for another site? Basically the same thing but moving the post attachments to a div rather than a list, and adding a class. Should be very quick to answer, but would pose a problem for me. Can create a new question?

Comment: Great! Feel free to vote the answer if it solved your question. I really encourage you to try for yourself, but I can help you!

Comment: Thanks - setting it up, but can only post a question every 90 minutes! Many thanks for your quick and clear answers - and really appreciate the comments that explain how it works - I'm learning a lot from you!

Comment: You are welcome! This website and the programmers community helped me a lot so I try to give my help when I can. I try to answer keeping the questioner logic to help him to assimilate the new things. Well, while you cannot post a new question, try for yourself, and if you cannot get it post your attempts on question post. The community will appreciate it!

Comment: Trying it now, and appreciating the beauty of your solution above for this question. Couple of questions about this one: what does the `(index)` on line 3 do? And, as per the suggestion in the other thread/post, do you need `($(this))` or could you just use `(this)`? Third, how is the `ul` being created on line 7? That seems to defy logic! And is it enough to simply have `$("<li>") at the beginning of that line - you don't need to 'echo' it or something to get it to display? Finally, the final line - trimming html - is pure witchcraft to me! Need to look into that.

Comment: Have posted the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175757/use-jquery-to-move-wordpress-post-attachments-to-per-post-dynamically-created-di