# Add Wordpress thumbnails to images attached to posts

Tags: wordpress, image, loops, post, attachment

I am trying to get WordPress to include the thumbnail image within the image tag of any image attached to a post, to make the thumbnail available to the RoyalSlider plugin. (I am hard-coding the plugin into the site - don't want to use the wordpress version for various reasons.)

The end goal is this:

```
 <img class="rsImg" src="image.jpg" data-rsTmb="small-image.jpg" alt="image description" />
```

i.e. WordPress displays the images attached to  a post, but within each one the relevant thumbnail is added in 'data-rsTmb'.

I would liked to be able to do this via some code inserted into a specific page template, rather than modifying the main loop, as I do not require this behavior for the whole site, just one slider that is created through a custom page template.

I currently have this:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail');
/*
$image[0] => url
$image[1] => width
$image[2] => height
*/
echo '<img class="rsImg" src="'. $image[0] .'" data-rsTmb="small-image.jpg" alt="image description" />';
```

Any help much appreciated!

---

EDIT: UPDATED TO SHOW CODE I AM USING ON THE SITE BASED ON SUGGESTIONS IN COMMENTS:

```
<?php

/*
    Template Name: Gallery
*/

?>
<?php query_posts('cat=7&amp;showposts='.get_option('posts_per_page=1')); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php 

$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full');
$th = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail');

echo '<img class="rsImg" src="'. $image[0] .'" data-rsTmb="'. $th[0] .'" alt="image description" />';

?>

<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

---

EDIT #2: Alternate code from comment in the [previous version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293171/modify-wordpress-loop-to-output-all-images-in-a-post-with-thumbnails-included-in/25319005?noredirect=1#comment39620913_25319005) - this code works, but not for every image (?!):

```
/*
    Template Name: Gallery
*/

?>

<?php query_posts('cat=7&amp;showposts='.get_option('posts_per_page=1')); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php 

$images =& get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent='.$post->ID );

foreach ( (array) $images as $imageID => $imagePost ) {
 // Getting the full image size and thumbnail
 $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imageID, 'thumbnail');
 $full = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imageID, 'full');

 echo '<img class="rsImg" src="'. $full[0] .'" data-rsTmb="'. $thumbnail[0] .'" alt="'. $imagePost->post_content .'" />';

}
?>

<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: I believe Fabio answer will solve your question. You use `wp_get_attachment_image`(http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image ) to get the thumbnail and full size of your images, save each array in one variable and call them into your `<img>` tag.

Comment: @Leo please see my comment on Fabio's comment.

Comment: @Leo No, can't get it to work.

Comment: What exactly is not working? It seems to be fine on your website. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, try this:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full');
$th = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail');

echo '<img class="rsImg" src="'. $image[0] .'" data-rsTmb="'. $th[0] .'" alt="image description" />';
```

of course you may need some adjustment, specially if you want to use a special size for the big image (instead of full size) but you'll get the idea

Comment: Thanks, but while this SHOULD work it seems to be having zero effect. See the 'GALLERY' section of the site [here](http://macayamagic.com/FirstOption/) (you need to click on 'gallery' in the nav bar at bottom of screen; inexplicably, the first slide is now white - but click this and the slider advances to the images) - if you look at the code, the images are showing as usual, without thumbnails embedded within the `<img>` tag. Any ideas?

Comment: I did check the site and it seems you're not using the same code, I don't see any output for the thumb or data-rsTmb, which at least should be empty, but you don't even have the element. Are you sure you're using the correct code?

Comment: I have updated the question to show the exact code I'm using on the site - seemed the easiest way to show it in a block.

Comment: @Leo I have also added the code from a comment on the earlier version of this question, see above. This is the code that is live on the site URL right now.